# Call SSRS Stored Procedure from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

I have a Report in SSRS that I need to deliver whenever a table in an Oracle DB is updated.

My plan was to create a trigger in the Oracle DB that on update would tell the Report in SSRS to deliver. The trigger would call a Stored Procedure in SSRS that would then use 'FireEvent SOAP API' to run the report.

I can't seem to find anything about calling SP's in SSRS from Oracle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am pretty new to this stuff.
(Been using SQL for about 2 weeks :/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use a stored procedure inside a package , for calling that SP I do the following :

- In the RDL file Click on Data tab to create a new Dataset .
- Select New Dataset , Select The data source and rename the Dataset .
- In the Command type , select Procedure instead of Text .
- In the Query string Box ,  write the name of the Procedure then click “OK”.

  *Name of Procedure within a package can be PKG_EXAMPLE.SP_NAME
  *Name of Procedure without a package can be SP_NAME

Hope this helps

Thanks,
Sufian.